# Mongo DB - What should I put to indexes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a query with `.sort()` and `.select()`:

```
Item.find({title: searchRegExp}).lean().select('slug title poster').limit(50).sort('-_id')
```

Should I put to MongoDB indexes:

1. query fields `{ title: 1 }`
2. sort fields `{ _id: -1 })`
3. select fields `{ slug: 1, title: 1, poster: 1 }`

or them all together? 
`{ title: 1, _id: -1, slug: 1, title: 1, poster: 1 }`

Comment: title and _id, I think (in this order)

Comment: order is also matter?

Comment: Order of index fields matters, of course.